# For which interest rates r is the model arbitrage-free?

Tags: interest-rates, arbitrage

> Given $\Omega=\{\omega_1,...,\omega_4\}$ and a probability measure
> $\mathbb{P}$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{P}(\Omega))$ where
> $\mathbb{P}(\{\omega_i\})>0$ for all $i$. Let, furthermore, $r\geq 0$,
> $S_0=5$ and
>
> $S_1(\omega_1)=S_1(\omega_2)=8$, $S_1(\omega_3)=S_1(\omega_4)=4$,
>
> $S_2(\omega_1)=9$, $S_2(\omega_2)=S_2(\omega_3)=6$, $S_2(\omega_4)=3$.
>
> For which interest rates $r$ is the model arbitrage-free?

I looked at the one-period arbitrage possibilities and got $r\in [0,1/3)$. I'd appreciate it if someone could double-check it since my textbook gives no solutions.

Comment: If it is a 2 period problem, aren't there going to be 2 interest rates, i.e. $r$ changes over time? Don't we need to look at them separately?

Comment: Maybe you could show us your analysis for the 1st period and we can check whether it makes sense or not.

Comment: @nbbo2 I think the situation is even worse than that -- might be a question of finding the set of rates that work at time 0, time 1 if the stock goes up, and time 1 if the stock goes down

Comment: $S_t^0=(1+r)^t$., so $1,1+r,(1+r)^2$.

Comment: Where should I post my work?

Comment: You can update the question by clicking on edit and adding your work below the question as it stands at the moment.